# Using Visual Studio as a Compiler for QT Creator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, boost

I've been trying to get Visual Studio to be the compiler I use for QT creator, so that I can link to my boost libraries that would for some reason only build in msvc.

When I look at my build and run tab it auto found 5 different visual studio compilers, yet none of them have paths to a debugger.

I tried cloning one and then I realized I couldn't even find the path to what I was supposed to put in the debugger.

Qt Creator 2.4.1 
Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)

Built on Jan 26 2012 at 09:48:31

From revision 8cd370e163

Visual Studio 2010

My computer is Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Debugging Tools for Windows (x64) from the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). Qt should then find it automagically.

Comment: So I just tried that and it's giving me an error (at the earlier stages of install)

11:41:46 AM Monday, June 04, 2012: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:....  It goes on for about 300 more characters.

Comment: Make sure you are installing it as an admin.