# Qt Creator no compiler

Tags: qt

it's my first time to try QT Creator on my Windows 8. But the problem is, it doesn't detect an existing compiler. My question is how can I add a compiler to get me started? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any compiler installed? MSVC compiler can be installed with Visual Studio or Windows SDK. MinGW compiler can be installed manually from the [official site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about how to add a compiler/kit (aka tool-kit, aka tool-chain) you can find it on a website called [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464075/qt-creator-how-to-add-a-compiler).  =)

All kidding aside, you may need to download a compiler such as [MinGW](http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/prebuilt/mingw_32/) or [Visual Studio Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589232/using-qt-5-0-with-qt-creator-and-vs2010-compiler).

Comment: Hi, I got in the MinGW site, what files do I need to download?